# jQuery Carousel Plugin showing unwanted border

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I am using showbiz jQuery carousel in my products page. When I clicked in view more button its showing a unwanted border on carousel in chrome only. How can I remove that??

here my code

```
<div style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;" align="center">
                <div class="example-wrapper">
                  <div id="services-example-1" class="theme1">
                    <ul>








<


                </ul>

                <!--    ###############     -   TOOLBAR (LEFT/RIGHT) BUTTONS    -   ###############  -->
                <div class="toolbar">
                  <div class="left">
                  </div>
                  <div class="right">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


          </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a focus element: just add it into your css:

```
*:focus{
    outline:0px;
}
```

I hate this issues, xDDDDDD

Comment: sorry I went for my lunch. Its worked thank you so much for your time. Thnks once again.

Answer (score 0):

An unwanted border`border: 1px #eee solid;` is applied to the div in the rendered html. It must have been generated by the jquery plugin. Search for it in the plugin and just delete it.

Comment: thanks for noticing me that, but its not the bordr. I have removed the style from html. did you see the border in chrome/safari?? its in blue colour. i have tried a lot to find solution for that but i couldn't.